# Windows Phone 8 MonoGame projects stopped working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, monogame

I'm not sure exactly what happen.

I had visual studio 2012 installed with MonoGame 3.0.1 and all the demos from the book (Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 Game Dev) everything was working.

However after not doing anything for a month i went back today to pick up on a game where i left off and i can no longer get my games to work. Theres a chance i upgraded visual studio or windows in between.

I also tried upgrading to MonoGame 3.2 and that did not solve the issue

The normal projects from the book work (the windows game demos) and a new windows phone app with the default controls work.

I'm mostly a Linux developer so a little stumped on what could of happen with the windows phone games.

My output when run the demo games is below, i'm continuing to look into it, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:  When i say "stopped working" i mean the games compile and the emulator gets loaded but then its just a black screen.  Where as before there was animation.  Also these are the books demos, not mine.  They worked before

> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{F13744CE-A3B0-426B-8A4A-CF6F482B80CD}\Install\AnimationFrames_WP8.DLL'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{F13744CE-A3B0-426B-8A4A-CF6F482B80CD}\Install\MonoGame.Framework.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{F13744CE-A3B0-426B-8A4A-CF6F482B80CD}\Install\SharpDX.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{F13744CE-A3B0-426B-8A4A-CF6F482B80CD}\Install\SharpDX.Direct3D11.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{F13744CE-A3B0-426B-8A4A-CF6F482B80CD}\Install\SharpDX.XAudio2.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was
>   built without symbols. An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{F13744CE-A3B0-426B-8A4A-CF6F482B80CD}\Install\SharpDX.DXGI.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. The program '[3320] TaskHost.exe'
>   has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Try to update SharpDX to newest and change all references to it in your solution

Comment: tried that but didn't do anything.  Ended up uninstalling MonoGame and re-installing it through nuget and the issue seems to be resolved.  Now i just need to figure out how to create the project templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyed about what happen i spent a few hours tracking it down.

I had MonoGame 3.0.1 installed.  When i downloaded the 3.2 windows installation file some or all of the DLL's for the framework where throwing the errors.

I did complete uninstall and re-installs but the 3.2 version never works.

Then i use the nuget package manager to install MonoGame, and everything worked perfectly.

I'm thinking the 3.2 package is corrupt, or there is a dependency required that i'm not installing when i use the win installation package.